# Bipartite graph: Average number of cuts for a given partition

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Say I have a graph with an even number of nodes. We then randomly connect those nodes. The possible number of combinations boils down to $P=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!}$. We now make a partition of length $L$ on the graph, such that $L\in(1,n)$. This partition splits the graph into two subsets, and my question is: Given the randomly connected nodes, how many nodes will a partition cut? I attach a picture that I hope will helps understand the problem.[image]

We define the average number of cuts as $Q(n,L)$. For n=2, we have a 4 nodes graph and there are $P=3$ ways to create edges. However, for the partition L=2, it will only cut the graph in two of the three possible cases. For n=3, there are 15 possible combinations, which I do not draw all of them.

I was able to almost find a general expression for it, $Q(n,L)=(P-x)L+xL$, where $P$ is defined before as the total number of combinations and $L$ is the partition. The problem is that I do not know how to express the factor $x$, nor do I know if this really generalizes.

It seems like a problem known for graph theory and may be related to cuts (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(graph_theory)), but I am not sure.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edited: As asked in the comments, I attach a picture of all the n=3 possible combinations for L=3 and L=2 (L=1 is the trivial case). Notice how the geometry is a bit different, as they are no longer on a circle, but rather on two sets. [image]

Comment: Maybe worth highlighting that your partition implicitly arises from embedding and choosing a half-space; that is, can't (for example) choose only the left and right nodes in the bottom-right "$u=2$" diagram.

Comment: @JacobManaker I think you are refereing where I put my partition? It is actually arbitrary and does not really matter because we are considering all permutations of edges.

Comment: Do you have all the $n=3$ configurations ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_diagram_(mathematics) ... Can you make a table of the values you wany to generate ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit I edited the post to add all possible n=3 configurations for L=3 and L=2 (L=1 is the trivial case). And thanks for the reference, it may help me find the answer.

Comment: I would write $P=(2n-1)!!$ (but it's same thing) ... anyway, have a look at OEIS https://oeis.org/A001147

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $L\times (2n-L)$ pairs of vertices such that the two vertices are on opposite sides of the cut. For each of these pairs of the vertices, $x$ and $y$, the probability that they are joined by an edge in the matching is $1/(2n-1)$; this is because $x$ is equally likely to be joined to each of the other $2n-1$ vertices.

Therefore, by linearity of expectation, the expected number of edges crossing the cut is
$$
L\times (2n-L)\times \frac1{2n-1}. 
$$
This is the expected number of cut edges. The quantity $Q(n,L)$ you are computing is something more like the total number of cut edges over all possible matchings. To go from expected to total, you multiply by the size of the probability space, which is the number of mathcings, equal to $$P = (2n)!/(2^nn!) = (2n-1)(2n-3)(2n-5)\cdots 1:=(2n-1)!!.$$ It follows that
$$
Q(n,L) = L\times (2n-L)\times \frac1{2n-1}\times (2n-1)!! = L\times (2n-L)\times (2n-3)!!
$$
This agrees with what you already found. For example,
$$
Q(3,3) = 3\times 3\times 3!! = 3\times 3\times 3=27\\
Q(3,2) = 2\times 4\times 3!! = 24\\
Q(3,1) = 1\times 5\times 3!! = 15
$$
For a further example,
$$
Q(4,3) = 3\times (8-3)\times 5!! = 3\times 5\times (5\times 3\times 1)=225
$$

Comment: That is the complete answer! Thank you! Still, I am a bit confused, as I was expecting a different answer. The answer I expected was somewhat that, for large n, $Q\simeq \log(L)$ (I checked with Mathematica in this limit they are not the same). I say that because the origin of the problem comes from a known physics result: (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.6008.pdf and https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0406737.pdf) If you make cuts of length L at a 1D chain made of random pairs, the number of cut bonds goes as log(L).

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure what the reason for the discrepancy is. I glanced at the papers, and noticed that in all of the diagrams, there where never any connections which crossed each other. If the random matching is restricted to noncrossing matchings like this, that would change the analysis, and might produce the $\log L$ result.

Comment: Indeed, one of the papers says "The qualitative picture of the ground state generated in this process shown in Fig. 1 looks like a random arrangements of non crossing singlet pairs occuring at all scales." It might be interesting to see what happens in a uniformly random non-crossing matching (explicitly: choosing each non-crossing matching of $2n$ points with probability $\frac1{C_n}$, where $C_n$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)).

Comment: @MishaLavrov Could you also guide me on how to do it with the Catalan numbers? I tried and failed at getting it (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4615509/how-to-count-pairs-with-catalan-distribution)