# How to count pairs between odd-even number given a partition between sets

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I am trying to solve a combinatorics problem which I do not know how to generalize. Let's say we have two sets of $n$ elements. We label set 1 with odd numbers and set 2 with even numbers.

For example, for n=3

Set 1: $1\ 3\ 5$
Set 2: $2\ 4\ 6$

In general, there are $n!$ ways to pair set 1 with set 2. For example, in this case, 3!=6 ways: {1,2}{3,4}{5,6}, {1,2}{3,6}{5,4}, {1,4}{3,2}{5,6}, {1,4}{3,6}{5,2}, {1,6}{3,4}{5,2}, and {1,6}{3,2}{5,4}.

Up until here is fine. Now we consider that set 1 and 2 can be partitioned into two distinct sets such that I always split the set into ${\rm integer}(n/2)$ elements or less. Let's call them set L and set R.

${\rm L}\Big|\ {\rm R}$
$1\Big|\ 3\ 5$
$2\Big|\ 4\ 6$

Now the elements within set L $\textbf{cannot}$ be paired together, only with the set L-R, R-L and R-R. In the example before, the allowed pairing is only 4: {1,4}{2,3}{5,6}, {1,4}{2,5}{3,6}, {1,6}{2,3}{4,5}, and {1,6}{2,5}{3,4}.
Another example, for n=4 which has two possible partitions L=1 and L=2:

${\rm L}\Big|\ {\rm R}$
$1\Big|\ 3\ 5\ 7$
$2\Big|\ 4\ 6\ 8$

Here there are 18 possible combinations: {1,4}{2,3}{5,6}{7,8}, {1,4}{2,3}{5,8}{7,6},{1,6}{2,3}{5,4}{7,8}, {1,6}{2,3}{5,4}{7,6}, etc.

${\rm L}\Big|\ {\rm R}$
$1\ 3\Big|\ 5\ 7$
$2\ 4\Big|\ 6\ 8$

Here there are 20 possible combinations {1,8}{2,3}{4,5}{7,6}, {1,8}{2,7}{3,6}{4,5}, etc.

I attach a pictorial graph to help grasp the idea:

[image]

I am now trying to generalize the number of possible pairings in the function of $n$ and the size of $L$. I asked a similar, but more trivial, question here:[Bipartite graph: Average number of cuts for a given partition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4572979/bipartite-graph-average-number-of-cuts-for-a-given-partition). And the answer should be somewhat similar, but I cannot find a way to solve it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In your second example, why is $\{5,6\}$ allowed to be part of a pairing? Or is the rule that L-L pairs are not allowed, but L-R, R-L, and R-R pairs are all fine?

Comment: @MishaLavrov You are completely right, my mistake: R-R pairs are allowed. I edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Pairings with no $L$-to-$L$ pairs

Suppose that there are $2\ell$ elements in $L$ ($\ell$ on the top, $\ell$ on the bottom) and $2r$ elements in $R$ ($r$ on the top, $r$ on the bottom) with $\ell \le r$.

Then there are $r(r-1)(\cdots)(r-\ell+1) = \frac{r!}{(r-\ell)!}$ ways to pair the top-left elements with bottom-right elements. Independently, there are $\frac{r!}{(r-\ell)!}$ ways to pair the bottom-left elements with top-right elements. After that is done, there are $r-\ell$ elements left on each side of $R$, which can be matched in $(r-\ell)!$ ways, for an overall count of $$\frac{r!^2}{(r-\ell)!}$$
pairings.

### Pairings with exactly $2k$ crossing pairs

Using the same notation as the above (but dropping the now-unnecessary assumption that $\ell \le r$) let's count the number of pairings with $2k$ crossing pairs: $2k$ pairs where one element is in $L$ and one element is in $R$. The number of these must be even, because the number of top-left-to-bottom-right pairs must be equal to the number of bottom-left-to-top-right pairs.

There are $\binom \ell k^2 \binom rk^2$ ways to pick which elements of $L$ and $R$ are going to be part of crossing pairs. From there, there are $k!$ ways to pick the top-left-to-bottom-right pairs, and $k!$ ways to pick the bottom-left-to-top-right pairs.

The remaining $2(\ell-k)$ elements of $L$ can be paired in $(\ell-k)!$ ways, and the remaining $2(r-k)$ elements of $R$ can be paired in $(r-k)!$ ways. Altogether, we get
$$
   \binom \ell k^2 \binom rk^2 k!^2 (\ell-k)! (r-k)! =  \ell!\,r!\,\binom \ell k \binom rk
$$
pairings.

The $k=\ell$ case gives us the formula in the previous section.

The $k=0$ case gives us the $\ell!\,r!$ pairings with no crossing pairs at all. Since there are $(\ell+r)!$ pairings total, we also know that $(\ell+r)! - \ell!\,r!$ gives us the number of pairings with at least one crossing pair.

### The total number of crossings across all pairs

Another thing that seems useful is the total number of crossings added up over all pairings, where each of the $ \ell!\,r!\,\binom \ell k \binom rk$ pairings with $2k$ crossings contributes $2k$ to the count.

We can express this as a summation over all $k$ from $0$ to $\min\{r,\ell\}$, but there is an easier way. There are $2r\ell$ possible crossing pairs, and each one of them appears in $(r+\ell-1)!$ pairings (since the other $r-\ell-1$ elements on the top and bottom need to be paired somehow). Therefore, in total, there are $$2r\ell (r+\ell-1)!$$ crossings among all the pairings.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! However, it is not correct... At n=4, it does not gives the proper result for l=1 and r=3. With your formula, it gives 72, but by counting them I got 18 (Look at my drawing, the bottom one).

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in the simplifcation - $r(r-1)(\cdots)(r-\ell+1)$ should be $\frac{r!}{(r-\ell)!}$. I fixed it.

Comment: Great! It works for l=1. There is something amiss... For n=4 and l=2 r=2, your formula gives me 4, which should actually be 20... Probably I explained the problem wrong: If you look at my drawing, what I do is count pairs that cross the boundary between L and R, taking into account all possible permutations within L and R. There are 4 combinations where 4 bounds are cut (this is probably your 4), while there are 16 other combinations where only 2 bounds are cut.

Comment: Oh, I see that in your list you are giving examples like the pairing $\big\{\{1,8\}, \{2,3\}, \{4,5\}, \{7,6\}\big\}$. I excluded this in my count, because you said that elements within $L$ cannot be paired together, which rules out the pair $\{2,3\}$. Can you clarify what you want?

Comment: You are right, I need to clarify this: What I need to do it count how many pairs between L and R are formed. For example: {{1,8},{2,3},{4,5},{7,6}} is 1 bound/pair between L and R for both l=1 and l=2. However, {{1,2},{3,8},{5,6} {7,4}} gives 1 bound for l=2  but 0 for l=1. This is why in my drawing, I draw partitions and count the number of cuts.

Comment: I've added the answers to some of the other problems you seem to be trying to solve; let me know if I've missed anything.

Comment: You completely got it! The last part is exactly what I needed: To count the total number of cut bounds for a given L and R. Your answer is quite elegant, thank you!